# Buildozer crashes only with release command

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I created an APK file with buildozer and it all works. Then I made a release and uploaded to the play store. I forgot the app icon and when I add the icon to the .spec file the release doesnt happen. It works clearly with debug mode on my phone the icon is clear as well and there is no error on logcat. When its come to release with icon it crashes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
> Task :mergeReleaseResources FAILED
[DEBUG]:    Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.
[DEBUG]:    > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Try:
[DEBUG]:    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[DEBUG]:    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[DEBUG]:    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUİLD FAILED in 27s
[DEBUG]:    9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
Exception in thread background thread for pid 2238:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/hakki/siirkarma/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/siirkarma__arm64-v8a/gradlew assembleRelease

  STDOUT:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
/home/hakki/siirkarma/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/siirkarma__arm64-v8a/src/main/res/drawable/icon.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
/home/hakki/siirkarma/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/siirkarma__arm64-v8a/src/main/res/drawable/icon.png: error: file failed to compile.

> Task :mergeReleaseResources FAILED
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUİLD FAILED in 27s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date





[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 34):
[DEBUG]:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    
    
* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'. 
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details  
    
* Try:  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.    
    
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  
    
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. 
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.   
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings   
    
BUİLD FAILED in 27s 
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date    

[INFO]:    STDERR:
    
[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/hakki/siirkarma/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/siirkarma__arm64-v8a && /home/hakki/siirkarma/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/dists/siirkarma__arm64-v8a/gradlew assembleRelease

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/hakki/siirkarma/.buildozer/android/platform
```

/build-arm64-v8a/dists/siirkarma__arm64-v8a/gradlew failed!

Comment: Post the error.

Answer (score 0):

It was about the png file. I renamed my .jpeg to .png . It has to be reformatted not just renamed. Open the jpeg with paint and save as png.